# Break a filter into two different filters in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have one column product and other product type.i have two filters Product and Type from them.
Now i want to create filter in such a way that i have first filter as
1)Product(where productType=A)
and 2nd as 
2)Product(where productType=B).

Please let me know how can i achieve this in Tableau.

**Currently the data is shown in two columns is like:**

```
Product         Type
A               New
B               Old
C               Old
D               New
E               New
```

**I want two filters and they should be like this:**

```
New Product         Old Product
A                       B
D                       C
E
```

Comment: Visually speaking how many filters do you need? 1 ore 2?
In addition, could you please add a simple input and output to make it more clear?

Comment: @FabioFantoni: I want two filters and i have added some data.Thanks

Comment: You can create a `set` on the dimension and use those as filters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a calculated field `product_a_filter` as

```
case when type = 'A' then product end
```

use this calculated field as filter .Similarly for product type B.

note you will get NULL as extra value in the filter .

to remove that follow this link below :

[remove null from filter](http://reports4u.co.uk/tableau-hide-values-quick-filter/)

Comment: Can this calculated field be then used as a global filter(that is to filter all worksheets that share same data source)